# How to share the AWS keys without people knowing about it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a use case where in I have installed a private instance of webpagetest http://www.webpagetest.org on EC2 . Now I want to enable autoscaling of the webpagetest AMIs . Now for autoscaling the AMI , I need to mention the AWS secret key and access key here in the configuration. https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/www/settings/ec2.ini.sample

Now the team that handles AWS in my organization are hesitant to give me the keys.

Is there a work around for problem like this. Can the keys be shared in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to create an IAM role, and assign it to the EC2 instance.

You can't assign a role to an existing instance, so you will have to recreate your instance.

The AWS documentation for this is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)